# In robotframework, for the robot command, the variable switch is not taking values with space in them

Tags: python, shell, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am running my robotframework tests using a shell script.
I am able to pass variables and include them in the robot command and execute them just fine.

However, if my variable value contains a Space character in it, the robot command fails to execute.

my test.sh script

```
if [ -z "$DATEFORMAT" ]; then
    DATEFORMAT="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
else
    DATEFORMAT=$DATEFORMAT
fi

echo dateformat=$DATEFORMAT

robot --variable dateformat:$DATEFORMAT system_test/features/test.robot
```

when executed, this results in the below error:

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'hh:mm' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.

Try --help for usage information.
```

if i remove the character Space from the DATEFORMAT value, then it executes just fine.

```
DATEFORMAT="dd/mm/yyyyhh:mm"
```

I tried including the $DATEFORMAT in the robot command in the quotes, but still getting the same error.

```
robot --variable dateformat:"'"$DATEFORMAT"'" system_test/features/test.robot
```

Comment: I think you overdid it with the quotes, why so many? I think just a single quote at the beginning and eft of the var should do it? _(single vs double, as they'll stop the shell from substituting any variable-lookalike in the value)_

Comment: Varibale subsitution was needed here. Instead of `dateformat:"'"$DATEFORMAT"'" `, now used `dateformat:"${DATEFORMAT}" `. The change here is the brackets around the variable. Yes, single quote was enough.

Comment: when echo both commands in terminal, 1>`robot --variable dateformat:$DATEFORMAT` and 2>`robot --variable dateformat:"${DATEFORMAT}"` both give the same answer as `robot --variable dateformat:dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`. But only the command 2 works. why is that?

Comment: You may have to "export DATEFORMAT" to have it usable in robot.